# Why isn't my JSP file mapping to my Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I have just began learning spring and I have added a jsp file to my project but the controller can't map to it. My controller is in *src --> main --> java --> com.example.todo --> controller --> **UserController.java***  and my jsp file is in src --> main --> resources --> WEB-INF --> jsp --> ***index.jsp.*** I am following a video in which the person adds jsp file to spring project and the controller maps it. But in my case it is not doing.

[image]

[image]

This is my code -

**TodoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.todo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TodoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.example.todo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String ind(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/index-html")
    @ResponseBody
    public String indexHTML(){
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();

        body.append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        body.append("<html>");
        body.append("<body>");
        body.append("<h1>HTML page</h1>");
        body.append("<p>This is a random text</p>");
        body.append("</body>");
        body.append("</html>");

        return body.toString();
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1 style="color: blue;">This is jsp file</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>todo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>todo</name>
    <description>A To-Do list application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db
```

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community with JDK 19 and spring 3.1 on Ubuntu 22.04. When I goto **localhost:8080/index-html** it renders the html code and performs as expected, but it isn;t the case when I go to **localhost:8080/index.**

I have also made changes to application.properties, added the prefix and suffix, and added the tomcat-jasper dependency.

Please help. Also will be glad if you can provide a good online resource for learning spring boot.

Comment: WARN 65189 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : "Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp]" 
This is what I get in the terminal

Comment: `WEB-INF.JSP` is not the same as a nested directory `WEB-INF/JSP`--can't tell from the screenshot which it is.

Comment: I added the jsp sub-directory inside WEB-INF directory. How is it different?

Comment: Re-worded: A directory named `WEB-INF.JSP` is not the same as a directory named `JSP` in the directory named `WEB-INF`. It's not clear what you had *(or have now)*.

Comment: WEB-INF has only one dir in it i.e. jsp, that's why in the screenshot it is appearing as WEB-INF.jsp, but actually it is a directory

Answer (score 0):

**better check that the jsp created is under right path**

you can learn about spring boot from [HowTodoInJava](https://howtodoinjava.com/series/spring-boot-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot,JSPs on embedded server and Jar packaging do not play well.

With Jetty and Tomcat, JSPs should work if you use war packaging. An executable war will work when launched with java -jar, and will also be deployable to any standard container. JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar.
[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.embedded-container.jsp-limitations)

You can check out a working example [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jsp-view-example/).